# Delete 75% Of a Table Randomly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to make a smaller sample database but still have the data be somewhat statistically relevant.  How can I delete x % of rows from the table ?  Been fooling around with the NEWID() function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE PK IN (SELECT TOP (75) PERCENT PK
             FROM TABLE_NAME
             ORDER BY NEWID())
```

*Suggestion by Martin Smith*

```
DELETE T 
FROM (SELECT TOP (75) PERCENT * 
      FROM TABLE_NAME 
      ORDER BY NEWID()) T
```

Comment: I was fooling around with that did not know the percent function !  Thanks will mark when I can

Comment: `DELETE T FROM (SELECT TOP (75) PERCENT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY NEWID()) T` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be:

```
DELETE 
FROM table_name
WHERE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 < 75 ;
```

It will **not** delete exactly 75% of the rows but it will be faster for a bigger table, as it won't need to do a sort.

Answer (score 1):

My working example on Azure SQL Database (most syntax compatible with SQLServer):

```
delete TOP (75) PERCENT 
FROM outer_sources.del_me_tbl
```